# PHP and MySql update

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm newbie in PHP sorry. How can i update a user defined var in user defined table with user defined value in MySql? I cant get it work.

```
<?PHP
$table = $_POST['table'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$key = $_POST['key'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$con = mysql_connect("mysql.serversfree.com","u105645000***","mf***") or ("Cannot connect!"  . mysql_error());
if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("u10564500***" , $con) or die ("could not load the database" . mysql_error());
/*$mysql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table ($key) VALUES ('".$value."');");*/
$sql = "UPDATE $table Set ".$key."='".$value."'";
?>
```

Comment: you have so many issues.... __1__) why you are allowing users to chose table? __2)__ sql injection __3)__ your whole table will be updated with the identical data __4)__ stop using `mysql_*` functions

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 the whole query is controlled by users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why your code is not working

You're not launching the query.

### No where clause

Without specifying any conditions, *every record* of the coulmn $key will be updated with $value.

### Solution

Use this code:

```
<?PHP
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.serversfree.com","u105645000***","mf***","u10564500***");
$table = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['table']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id']);
$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['key']);
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['value']);
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));}
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ".$table." Set ".$key."='".$value."'");
?>
```

Comment: @itachi I noticed about the risk of SQL injection (if you're referring to that) as I posted my answer, I edited it.

Comment: @itachi we don't know database configuration of OP or what they need to do, maybe there's just one record per table...
Anyway, I'm editing my answer pointing that out. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: _Still Not works_ is NOT a PHP error. tell us what error you got.

Comment: i got this error: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,

Comment: if the error message continues with "bool given", then you should check your data for connection to database